# Just a little sum-thing

Tags: mathematics

Select 5 numbers.  Using exactly five copies of each, simultaneously create 15 (multi-)sets, one of each sum from 1 to 15 inclusive.

Thanks to [Gordon Hamilton](http://mathpickle.com/project/12-days-addition-logic-factoring/) for the inspiration...

Comment: Despite a successful solution (though perhaps not the only one possible!),  it seems that some confusion remains.  Could you please let me know what needs clarification, so that I can improve the puzzle?  Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We must select 5 numbers with sum $\frac{1}{5}(1+2+\dots+15) = \frac{1}{5} \cdot 120 = 24.$

Select $1, 3, 5, 7, 8.$ Here is the list:

$1$

$1, 1$

$3$

$1, 3$

$5$

$3, 3$

$7$

$8$

$8, 1$

$5, 5$

$8, 3$

$7, 5$

$8, 5$

$7, 7$

$8, 7$

Motivation: $1$ is forced. I tried adding $2$ next, but that would've forced me to use a number above $8$ ($\min \max = 9$ achieved with $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 9\}$), so I added $3$ to the list. The only 5 element set with $1, 3$ and $\max \le 8$ was $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 8\},$ and it worked.

Comment: Nicely done!  The solution is unique if you restrict to natural numbers.